# How to find the image name using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here in this html i need to get the image name arrow_down using jquery and set it in a variable x.Here in my code after getting the image name i have to use that name in if else condition

```
 <a style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;" id="imageDivLink" href="#">
 <img name="arrow" class="img-swap" src="Images/arrow_down.jpg" width="13" height="13" border="0" alt="" /></a>
```

and

```
     $('#imageDivLink').click(function () {
            var x = $("img[src$='arrow_down.jpg'][name='arrow']");

      if (x == arrow_down) {
           $('#MainContent_IFTrendAnalysis').animate({ height: '+=120' }, 500);
        }
        else {
           $('#MainContent_IFTrendAnalysis').animate({ height: '-=120' }, 500);
        }
 });
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: $('#imageDivLink').children('img').attr('name'); should work

Comment: Do you want the `name` attribute or the image name found in the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use attr("src") to get the src attribute.

```
$('#imageDivLink').click(function () {
        var x = $("img[src$='Images/arrow_down.jpg'][name='arrow']");

  if (x.attr("SRC") == "Images/arrow_down.jpg") {
       $('#MainContent_IFTrendAnalysis').animate({ height: '+=120' }, 500);
    }
    else {
       $('#MainContent_IFTrendAnalysis').animate({ height: '-=120' }, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

bart s is mostly right - but to complete the jquery:

```
$('#imageDivLink').on('click',function () {
    var imgName = $(this).find('img').attr('name');

    if(imgName === 'arrow_down') {  
        //do something 
       }
    else {  
        //do something else 
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would give the image an ID like below

```
<img name="arrow" class="img-swap" id="myImage" src="Images/arrow_down.jpg" width="13" heigh="13" border="0" alt="" /></a>
```

Then using jquery you can grab the attribute name like this

```
var imageName = $('#myImage').attr('name');
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use the .attr() function provided by jQuery.

You can create custom attribute & the access it in jQuery.

Example

Then in jQuery
$().jQuery(function(){

```
var v=$('#id').attr('CustomName');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<img class="zoom_img" src="images/8.jpg" id="my_img" name="my_img"/>
```

**jQuery:**

To get the name by using class name use the below example:

```
$('.zoom_img').click(function(e){
    var fileName = $(this).attr('src');
    var fieldName = $(this).attr('name');       
    alert('FileName : ' + fileName + '\nFieldName : ' + fieldName);
});
```

To get the name by using field id use the below example:

```
$('#my_img').click(function(e){
    var fileName = $('#my_img').attr('src');
    var fieldName = $(this).attr('name');       
    alert('FileName : ' + fileName + '\nFieldName : ' + fieldName);
});
```

**Note:** When using field id, we can get the value either by using field id or ***this*** keyword.